# A problem involving the largest prime divisor of polynomials of the form $a^2+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math, pell-type-equations

**Question:**

Let $P(a)$ be the largest prime positive divisor of $a^2 + 1$. Prove that there exist infinitely many positive integer tuples $a, b, c$ ( all three distinct) such that $P(a)=P(b)=P(c)$.

I could show that we could find infinitely many pairs $a,b$ such that $P(a)=P(b)$ quite easily .
Using the fact that $a^2-2b^2=1$ has infinitely many solutions which rearranges to $a^2+1=2(b^2+1)$ which implies $P(a)=P(b)$.But I could not solve the original problem.

Any kind of hint or solution will be appreciated.

Comment: [OEIS sequence A014442](https://oeis.org/A014442)  and references there may be helpful.

Comment: Hint: $(n^2+1)(4n^2+1)^2=(4n^3+3n)^2+1$.

Comment: @JohnTom I am sorry. Can you please further elaborate?

Comment: I am sorry that hint was not useful, see this https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h404321p2254550

Answer (score 1):

Because prime divisors of quantities like this are decently badly behaved, you're going to want to look at some values that factor nicely Say we want some polynomial $P(a)$ so that
$$a^2+1 \big| P(a)^2+1.$$
This is equivalent to $a^2+1 \big | (P(a)-a)(P(a)+a)$, which gives the two obvious solutions $P(a)=a^2-a+1$ and $P(a)=a^2+a+1$. Indeed, we see that
$$(a^2-a+1)^2+1=(a^2+1)(a^2-2a+2)$$
and
$$(a^2+a+1)^2+1=(a^2+1)(a^2+2a+2).$$
So, we will have that $P(a)=P(a^2-a+1)=P(a^2+a+1)$ as long as $P(a)\geq P(a-1),P(a+1)$. So, we've reduced the problem from showing some equalities to showing some inequalities; essentially, we want that the sequence $P(a)$ has infinitely many local maxima.

One thing you've shown is that $P(a)=P(b)$ has infinitely many solutions. If you look somewhere between these $a$ and $b$, do you necessarily have a local maximum?